# ¿Como poner un input file el cual se pueda pinchar en una imagen?

Tags: html, angular

Por favor me gustaría que me ayudaran a dentro de un **div** colocar un input file al cual pueda seleccionar una imagen.

```
<div class="" (click)="()" >
                <input id="" type="file" (change)="()">
                <img class="" src={{img}} (click)="">
                <p class="">Texto de ejemplo</p>
              </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Podrías simplemente agregar un [`label`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/HTML/Elemento/label):

### Opcion 1:

Si el `label` contiene tanto el `input` como el `img`, entonces al hacer `click` sobre `img` será como si hubiese hecho `click` sobre el `input`.

#### Demo:

```html
<div class="" (click)="()">
  <label>
    <input id="" type="file" (change)="()">
    <img class="" src={{img}} (click)="">
  <label>
  <p class="">Texto de ejemplo</p>
</div>
```

### Opcion 2:

Si el `label` contiene solo el `img` y además le agregarmos el atributo `for` cuyo valor sea igual al `id` del `input`, entonces al hacer `click` sobre `img` será como si hubiese hecho `click` sobre el `input`.

#### Demo:

```html
<div class="" (click)="()">
  <input id="archivo" type="file" (change)="()">
  <label for="archivo">
    <img class="" src={{img}} (click)="">
  <label>
  <p class="">Texto de ejemplo</p>
</div>
```